# Play! Framework Scala Form Submitbutton

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0

I used the [Play! ScalaForm](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaForms) Tutorial to learn how to use Forms.

I got it working. It now shows 2 Inputboxes there I can write UserName and Password into. But the Tutorial doesn't tell me how to submit the Form.

**So how to Submit the Form?**

Overall I'm trying to implement en Loginscreen.

Project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Bersacker/ChatSystem)

And a follow up Question I want to redirect to the Home.html.
Tryed it with Action and with Redirect but can't get it working.

Comment: Like any other HTML form: `<input type="submit" value="MyLabel">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I got it working [GitHub branch](https://github.com/Bersacker/ChatSystem/tree/loginScreen)

I had to add

```
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

and change the method from val to def